# Load json file with multiple json objects from GCS bucket in python and process them one at a time

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have 1 json file in GCS bucket with below content.
fruit.json

```
{
    "fruit": "Mango",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Yellow"
}
{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "medium",
    "color": "Red"
}
{
    "fruit": "Grapes",
    "size": "small",
    "color": "Green"
}
```

In Python i want to process all those json object from that file, one at a time. How can I achieve that ?
I have tried below but it doesnt seems to be working:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('my-buckket_main1')
blob = bucket.blob('fruit.json')

objectList = []
fruitjson = json.loads(blob.download_as_string(client=None))
print(fruitjson)
print("Started Reading JSON file which contains multiple JSON document")
# with open(blob) as f:
for jsonObj in fruitjson:
    objectDict = json.loads(jsonObj)
    objectList.append(objectDict)

print("Printing each JSON Decoded Object")
for fruits in objectList:
    print(fruits["fruit"], fruits["size"], fruits["color"])
```

How can i process each json document in a file, one at a time to publish as a event to pubsub ?

Comment: When asking a question, if something doesn't work, include the output/error you're seeing. Is it possible to update your file so that it is a list of json objects?

Comment: getting below error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\gcp_poc\bucketInfo.py", line 18, in <module>
    fruitjson = json.loads(blob.download_as_string(client=None))
  File "C:\Users\maran28\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\maran28\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 6 column 1 (char 74)

Comment: Does this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62831544/how-to-write-and-read-json-objects-to-a-file-in-google-cloud-in-a-for-loop-using) help you?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution for my question asked above. **blob.download_to_filename(destination_uri)** did the job for me:

```
destination_uri = '{}/{}'.format(folder, 'newSample.txt')
blob.download_to_filename(destination_uri)

fruitList = []

with open(destination_uri) as f:
     for jsonObject in f:
         fruitDict = json.loads(jsonObject)
         fruitList.append(fruitDict)
```